# Eclipse brings up a terminal when starting

Tags: eclipse

Lately, when I install a new version of Eclipse, it opens a terminal with the executable, and if I close the terminal, the application also shuts down.

I can't quite figure out what's going on, but I think it's related to these lines in the Eclipse terminal:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 2858
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: C:\dev\workspaces\performance\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\logback.1.11.0.20190220-2119.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://695.fwk640275932:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://695.fwk640275932:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Application started in : 19945ms
```

Any ideas for me so that when I open Eclipse, only the application opens, and not a terminal as well?

---

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.300.v20190213-1655.jar
--launcher.library
C:\Users\user\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1000.v20190125-2016
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\dev\java\jdk-11\bin
-debug
C:\dev/.options
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms1g
-Xmx4g
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8001
-Doomph.redirection.egit=https://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/plain/tools/oomph/EGit.setup->file:/C:/dev/git/egit/tools/oomph/EGit.setup
```

[image: eclipse with terminal]

Comment: Please show your `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: @howlger added the ini file

Comment: I think it has to do with the way you launch eclipse. Is your OS Linux?

Comment: Does changing `C:\dev\java\jdk-11\bin` to `C:\dev\java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe` fix your issue? If not, remove the line `-debug` and the following line (any reason why you have this?).

Comment: `-debug` points to a properties file for use with the built-in tracing options. It wouldn't be relevant.

Comment: this is windows 10.  removing `-debug` resolved this for me, thanks @howlger!  i wasn't using this for anything myself - this was my first time using the oomph installer rather than downloading the package zip and extracting

Comment: @howlger changing to javaw solved the problem for me, could you add your comment as an answer please?